# Using "to" instead of printing each numbers in the array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

Is there a simple way to take the numbers which can be in the range and put a "to" in place of consecutive series?

So that for example if you had the following series of numbers:

```
$properties_no = array("1021-5152","1021-5153","1021-5154","1021-5156","1021-5157","1021-5158","1021-5159","1021-5161","1021-5162","1021-5163");
```

It would output:

```
1021-5152 to 1021-5154;
1021-5156 to 1021-5159;
1021-5161 to 1021-5163
```

Comment: It's worth noting that they're strings, not numbers, which complicates things, because you're instead trying to interpret and match consecutive pattern values. Is the prefix always `1021-`? What happens if you get one value alone with neither a preceding nor following consecutive value?

Comment: @fubar 1021-5152 to 1021-5154; 1021-5156; 1021-5158 to 1021-5159;

Comment: @fubar the prefix is not always 1021.

Comment: Are they always in the format `xxxx-yyyy`?

Comment: And if you have the value `1022-1564` at the end?

Comment: @fubar yes. Got a solution there?

Comment: @asdsad What about already posted answers?

Comment: It works for series xxxx-yyyy format numbers, but now Im having a problem with series xxxx-yyyy-a, xxxx-yyyy-b and so on.

Comment: @asdsad please provide some sample data that you are having issues with so the answers can be updated.

Answer (score 0):

To give yourself some flexibility, I'd define a simple `Range` class to hold ranges, and then make a function that builds a list of them.

Here's your `Range` definition:

```
final class Range
{
  private string $from;
  private string $to;

  public function __construct(string $from, string $to)
  {
    $this->from = $from;
    $this->to = $to;
  }

  public function __toString(): string
  {
    return $this->from === $this->to ? $this->from : "{$this->from} to {$this->to}";
  }
}
```

Here's the function:

```
/**
 * @param string[] $values
 * @return Range[]
 */
function computeRanges(array $values): array
{
  if (count($values) === 0) {
    return [];
  }
  $ranges = [];
  $first = $previous = $values[0];
  $previousIntValue = (int)str_replace('-', '', $first);
  foreach (array_slice($values, 1) as $value) {
    $intValue = (int)str_replace('-', '', $value);
    if ($intValue > $previousIntValue + 1) {
      $ranges[] = new Range($first, $previous);
      $first = $value;
    }
    $previous = $value;
    $previousIntValue = $intValue;
  }
  $ranges[] = new Range($first, $previous);

  return $ranges;
}
```

To print all the ranges (one per line):

```
echo implode(PHP_EOL, computeRanges($properties_no));
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/7EPCd**

Answer (score -1):

I have assumed that you already have the range in right order as you mentioned in the question.

```
$properties_no = array("1021-5152","1021-5153","1021-5154","1021-5156","1021-5157","1021-5158","1021-5159","1021-5161","1021-5162","1021-5163");
for($i = 0; $i < count($properties_no); $i++) {
    $next = $properties_no[$i+1] ?? null;
    echo $properties_no[$i] . $next ? ("to" . $properties_no[$next]) : "\n"; 
}
```

Hope this could help you!:)